# Modify HTTP Request value in Chrome automatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is there a way or an app to always change the value of a POST Request to a specific URL in Chrome?

Comment: Try modheader extension from chrome store

Answer (score 1):

Try [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). Specifically, `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener`

You would provide the string ["blocking"] as an attribute for the `opt_extraInfoSpec` parameter, and as a return value provide an object of type `BlockingResponse` which specifies what changes you want to make to the request.
Also, to get the body of the `POST` request, `opt_extraInfoSpec` also needs to contain the string `"requestBody"`

Your code would look something like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( function(details){
//
    if(details.method == "POST")
        var new_url = "http://stackoverflow.com/my_new_url";

    return {redirectUrl:  new_url}; 

}, ({urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"] }), ["blocking", "requestBody"]);
```

Dcoumentation at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

EDIT: The code you would place in the background page only.